# Add a sticky sidebar that is left-aligned to the right edge of the site wrapper

Tags: css, sidebar, sticky

I want to add a sticky sidebar that stays in place while you scroll down. [This site](https://web.archive.org/web/20120505031211/http://blog.kissmetrics.com/) has an example with its email opt-in form.

However, unlike that example, I want my sidebar to be left-aligned against the right edge of the wrapper.

Right now I'm just using

```
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 894px;
    top: 188px;
}
```

to position it, but it's not always against the right edge of the wrapper.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100px;
    position: fixed; 
    left:0; 
    top: 188px;
    }

.sidebar {
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
    }
```

This is an example of the wrapper being stuck to the left side of the screen and the sidebar is against the right side of the wrapper.

Comment: So close! Now my problem is that it's tethered to the right side of the window, not the right edge of the wrapper. Is it possible to place it on the outside edge of the wrapper? The wrapper is 658px wide.

Current code is .sidebar {position: fixed; right:0; top: 188px;}

Comment: I updated my answer.  You want the wrapper positioned to fixed and do whatever you want with the sidebar inside the wrapper.